# Form region to appear in customized ribbon outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

How can I programmatically put a reference to the custom ribbon I made so that the custom region I created will appear in that ribbon?

I see this is how you reference an outlook item. But I dont know how if its a customized ribbon.

```
 private void MapItFactory_FormRegionInitializing(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionInitializingEventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.ContactItem myItem = (Outlook.ContactItem)e.OutlookItem;
```

Comment: What particular ribbon interface do you need to reference? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am actually new in developing add-ins so my terms aren't that accurate. I want my programmatically created button that opens a map when click to appear in the Tab I made using the user interface of the outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a form region - use a [task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338197(v=office.12)). Since you are the one creating the task pane, you will have a reference to it (associated with a particular inspector). This way your button click event code can access your task pane.

Comment: I found that this is where you can initialize on where the button will appear. The button appeared in the Task Form.  `[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Task)]` but I will still try to use task pane